# How to move rows with same name into columns with python

Tags: python

What's I am trying to do:

---

Index   Summary

A   Mary

B   2.3

C   Female

A   John

B   4.6

C   Male

A   Gary

B   5.8

C   Male

---

A    B     C

Mary 2.3    Female

Jone 4.6    Male

Gary 5.8    Male

---

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Is this using Pandas? Can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: dont post images

Comment: Welcome, please post tables as text... your links show blabk tables on black background

Comment: You may be looking for Pandas pivot: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Just replicate your data
abc = ['A','B','C']
df = pd.DataFrame(['Mary',2.3,'Female','John',4.6,'Male','Gary',5.8,'Male'], columns = ['Summary'], index = abc*3)

#Store the data into a dictionary. Use the index as the key.
d={}
for x in np.unique(list(df.index)):
    d[x] = df.loc[x]['Summary'].tolist()

ndf = pd.DataFrame(d)
```